# Android Google Drive Send/Create Fiile

Tags: java, android, file, google-drive-api

Can someone show me short example how to send file from Android Phone to Google Drive?

Or Create new File with content and send to Drive.

Google example code on www site have errors or are from the new API but example app using old api..

**Google sample:**

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setTitle("photo.jpg");
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
        .setFields("id")
        .execute();
```

But methods like setTitle() and insert() not exists?

**My code:**

```
  HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Drive API Android Quickstart")
                    .build();

mService.files().create(new File().setName("TITLE").setMimeType("text/csv")).execute();
```

This creating file with name TITLE and correct MimeType.

**But how to send normal java.io.File or how to create content for drive.model.File ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet is close but there are a few differences between it and [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata):

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("config.json");
fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/config.json");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
```

- Use `setName` instead of `setTitle`
- Set the parent of the file to `appDataFolder`
- Use `driveService.files().create` instead of `driveService.files().insert`

Comment: But they are not using getGoogleApiClient() in fresh sample https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android 

Or Am I wrong? 
I remember getGoogleApiClient() in old Api but now wanted to use new.

Comment: It looks like you're right, the API has changed. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Almost. filePath in my case is not exists / created.

Comment: java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File("/data/user/0/com.PACKAGE/files/config.json");

With this file exists. So after some additional modifications and Your help I have what I wanted. Thx accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Google Drive app on your device. Well i think you already have.

After that use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user select a file from the drive which you then can read and write.

Or use Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT to let the user create a file-name on the drive where you than can copy your file to.

Comment: User will not interact with this. For example user will only write some information in EditTexts then I must complete this information and send this in file to Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20191108-1.30.3'
```

in your Gradle. And then in you class

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
```